# two child components in the same form in the parent - Angular

Tags: angular

### I develop a page in angular 7 who has this structure : (two large parties repeating themselves in the same form!)

CheckBox First Step :

```
      title : --------

      Message1 : --------

      Message2 : --------

      Message3 : --------

      Message3 : --------
```

CheckBox Second Step :

```
     title : -------

     Message1 : --------

     Message2 : --------

     Message3 : --------

     Message3 : --------
```

| Bouton Valider |

---

I cut the page into 2 components:

- a parent component
- a child component that is repeated twice in the form (First step, Second step)

My problems are:

1) If I put an id in the title field for the first step, it will be the same id for the second step if I reutilize the same child component in the parent component (forbidden in html to use the same identifier for two different fields)

2) How can I validate the form in the parent element in this case? Do I have to use one form or two forms: a form in each component?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: 1) Why would you use an ID ? 2) Implement the `ControlValueAccessor` interface on your child component, so that it behaves like an input and can be validated by the parent component

Comment: I will take a look on this concept, thanks :)

Comment: Do I have to use one form or two forms: a form in each component?

Comment: No form : the form is in the parent component. The child component becomes a form control.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Take a look at Reactive Forms : [Angular.io](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)

Comment: Hello, I know how to develop reactive forms, my concern is at the level of the division of the page (interaction between the components of this case): two large parties repeating themselves in the same form! and I the validation of data form for each component !

Comment: Use Inputs, complete example for you : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sm2zwk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: It works but I notice that there are 3 forms on your code, there would be no other way ?! for example use only one form parent and two forms controls childs ? I add that in your code , the parent who literally create the inputs of all the form! whereas if we start from the angular approach, it is the child who must create his own inputs form not her parent !!! what bothers me is that ultimately we have 3 html forms as result of this code !!!

Comment: there is only 1 form : i just pass the "parent" form to the child components with Input binding.

Comment: Anyway you'll need to isolate each formGroup child with an html tag : you can use a div rather than a form if you prefer. Talking about the angular approach, the best recommandation is to use smart/dump approach : so the child shouldn"t care about the form struture.

Comment: Thank you very much for these explanations :) I have another problem please: I need to use id attribute in some elements of the child component. The child component is used twice in the parent component, so I will have two elements with the same id !!!!!

Comment: what do you need the id attribute for?

Comment: For all that is css style, I use classes of a internal API; and I apply it to customize checkbox, so I use:
<input type = "checkbox" class = "some clasess ....." id = "checkbox1">
<label class = "some classes ...." for = "checkbox1">  ; without the "id" and the "for", style does not work

Comment: otherwise I could use the checkboxes in the parent component and I will avoid this problem !

Comment: knowing that once I uncheck a checkbox, the associated form (the child one) will be disabled

Comment: and I think it's better that I put the checkboxes in the parent component that enable / disabled the child form component

Comment: i found a way to keep unique id : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sm2zwk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fchild%2Fchild.component.html

Comment: i pass the name of the step to the child component and include it in the for/id name.

Comment: Post the answer here not in a broken link please